# Change Button text based on variable name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Issue: I want to change the text on some fixed named buttons.

When I run the routine I can see that `vButtonName` is correct however Dim Button As Button does not pick up the value?!

I have put first the .aspx.vb code then the .aspx button code

The text changes if I hardcode the button name.

**.aspx.vb Code:**

```
Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQL_DEMO").ToString()

For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Count - 1
    Using connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(OverallRiskCategory) FROM TblAsbestos WHERE OverallRiskCategory = @Category", connection)
            ' Open your connection '      
            connection.Open()

            ' Add your parameter '
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", arr(i).ToString())

            ' Execute your query '
            Dim result = command.ExecuteScalar()

            Dim vButtonName As String = "btnRiskRatingFilter" & arr(i).ToString() & "Text"

            Dim button As Button = FindControl(vButtonName)

            If Not button Is Nothing Then
                button.Text = String.Format("Class " & arr(i).ToString & " (" & result & ")")
            End If

            connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
Next
```

**.aspx code:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRiskRatingFilterAText" runat="server" Text="Class A"  CssClass="ButtonTextual"   OnCommand="btnRiskRating_Click"/>
```

Comment: you might want to add the appropriate asp tag

Comment: It's tagged with vb.net, what else where you thinking? edit: Done :-)

Comment: I see nothing wrong as such. Are you 100% sure the names you generate are OK ? Are your buttons created by codebehind or all included in your aspx page ? And VB.NET is not always ASP.NET, it might be anything from a console application to a service... so the remark from Plutonix is correct

Comment: The variable generate into vButtonName is btnRiskRatingFilterAText which (unless I've gone square eyed) matched the button ID. But Dim button As Button comes back as 'Nothing'

Comment: So the button is actually 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnRiskRatingFilter' and is in a page in a master page. Do I need to change the FindControl?

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that you should create the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and open the connection *outside* the loop. Inside the loop you can then just clear the command.Parameters collection and reset it each time. Right now you're creating and discarding a lot of objects and opening/closing database connections more than necessary.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I had to change the FindControl to find the master control then the contentholder:

*Dim button As Button = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl(vButtonName)*

Edit: I've also updated the layout of the code as per comments to improve the connections opening/closing

```
 Dim arr As New ArrayList
        arr.Add("A")
        arr.Add("B")
        arr.Add("C")
        arr.Add("D")
        arr.Add("NA")
        arr.Add("UN")

        ' Try

        Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQL_DEMO").ToString()
        Using connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            ' Open your connection '      
            connection.Open()
            For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Count - 1
                Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(OverallRiskCategory) FROM TblAsbestos WHERE OverallRiskCategory = @Category", connection)
                    ' Add your parameter '
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", arr(i).ToString())
                    ' Execute your query '
                    Dim result = command.ExecuteScalar()
                    Dim button As Button = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("btnRiskRatingFilter" & arr(i).ToString() & "Text")

                    If Not button Is Nothing Then
                        button.Text = String.Format("Class " & arr(i).ToString & " (" & result & ")")
                    End If
                End Using
            Next
            connection.Close()
        End Using

        'Catch ex As Exception
        'btnRiskRatingFilterAText.Text = "Unable to load"
        ' End Try
```